# external JS not loading properly in child views in Laravel5.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5.6

I am new to Laravel5.6 . I added the JS files in **Layout page** like this
with jquery CDN

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

@yield('script');
```

and in **Child View** added like this

```
  @extends('layouts.client')

  @section('content')

         *Some HTML CODE Here*

 @endsection

 @section('script')

  <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.easing.js') }}" />

  <script src="{{ asset('js/jqueryFileTree.js') }}" />

     <script type="text/javascript">  

        $(document).ready( function() {
          alert('hi');
        });

    </script>

 @endsection
```

and when i look the source using F12 then i found
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBLlM.jpg)

jqueryFileTree.js file is not showing in JS folder with other js in Network tab but in source, showing with black color(behave like simple text) unlike blue color link, shown in red circle.

Also doument.ready function not working. If i remove the both external js then ready function work well.

What going wrong ?, i am fail to catch.

Thank's in advance...